# What terms to use for figures related to questions and answers?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, expression-choice

I am working on implementing a Q&A platform and I am trying to find some catchy figure names for the following: how many questions were asked by non-staff (non-admin) and how many answers were provided by non-staff.

What I was able to come with so far:

- "Socratic index" - related to questions (inspired by the [Socratic badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/161/socratic)).
- "Knowledgeable index" - related to answers

Any idea about how to grasp the meaning I want?

I am interested in phrases related to questions and answers concepts only and it should not matter how I compute it.

**Question:** What terms to use for figures related to questions and answers?

Comment: @tchrist - sorry, I have removed that because it creates more confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a single word or short expression meaning both 'related to questions' and 'not submitted by staff'?  I'm afraid this seems to be trying to square the circle, and this is why 'suggest a name' requests have long been considered off-topic on ELU.

Comment: I see you've edited out the references to KPIs - but just to mention that any individual reportable indicator in statistics is normally called a "metric".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I am interested only a concept related to questions and answer respectively. Ë.g. "Socratic" clearly is related to questions.

Comment: @Astralbee - yes, you are right. I have removed it though, because I am looking for more artistic terms and metric sounds the opposite to me.

Comment: It is clear now (after your comment below) that you are asking for suggestions of catchy novel phrases. ELU is about established English usage, so this question is off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because naming things is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're creating some kind of *Knowledge Base*, and you're looking for a name for the statistical page that shows how many questions have been answered/asked.

I think you should stick to *nouns* rather than adjectives like "knowledgeable", because that sounds like you are describing the index as such, when actually it is an index *of* something (eg it isn't an index that is knowledgeable, it is an index *of* knowledge).

Perhaps:

- Insight Index
- Intelligence Index
- Expertise Index

Comment: Does it have to be "index"? If it is just a statistic on how many answered over how many asked, that is a *rate* or *ratio*. Otherwise I like all those nouns, +1.

Comment: @Astralbee - yes. "Insight rate" sounds OK.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Curiosity Index" for the questions and "Insight Rate" (@Astralbee's suggestion) for answers.

Comment: "Curiosity index" sounds good, although the term Socratic also suggests "good and tough".